# How to make pixel perfect font in css?

Tags: css

Could you please give me some tips how to make pixel perfect font from PSD to HTML / CSS3?

Currently I am using "

> font: 300 1.231em/42px "Signika",sans-serif;

"
the font in browser has got already the same height and width as in PSD, but the font in PSD has got slightly more color saturation.

Could you please help me to improve the color saturation of the font in CSS or any other idea of how to create pixel perfect and color perfect font?

Comment: The web is not desktop publishing.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: You can't control the way an HTML page displays, only make suggestions. The user can change the font size in their browser, or apply a custom stylesheet which overrides your styles, or any number of other things. Worry about the functionality and usability of your site, not trying to replicate a PSD.

Comment: Sure, but modern browsers are quite good in adapting the style from PSD, so I was expecting to get some tips about how to come as close as possible to PSD.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're trying to match a color, use the eyedropper to sample a color in Photoshop. Copy the hex value and set a CSS property with the same value. Ex:

```
p.myText {
color: #000000; /* black */
}
```

Comment: Hi, this I know and I am using it in the proper way.